# React return and render a component when state value changes

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am having an issue returning a component depending on a value. So firstly I have created state called activeIndex defaulted to 1, I then have 3 buttons that when clicked will change this state to either 1, 2 or 3 this works fine. Then the buttons also run a function called showTab() this checks the value of activeIndex and depending on what value that is equal to will return a different component. I then render this by putting { showTab } but when clicking the different buttons it does not show the different components.

```js
const Forcast = () => {
  // Create state to change tabs and return an index
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(1);
  const handleClick = (index) => setActiveIndex(index);
  const checkActive = (index, className) =>
    activeIndex === index ? className : "";
  
  // Create function to return a component depending on activeIndex value
  const showTab = (activeIndex) => {
    if (activeIndex === 1) {
        return <Today />
    } else if (activeIndex === 2) {
        return <Tomorrow />
    } else {
        return <SevenDays />
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="tabs">
        <button
          className={`tab ${checkActive(1, "active")}`}
          onClick={() => {handleClick(1); showTab();}}
        >
          Product Info
        </button>
        <button
          className={`tab ${checkActive(2, "active")}`}
          onClick={() => {handleClick(2); showTab();}}
        >
          Customer Reviews
        </button>
        <button
          className={`tab ${checkActive(3, "active")}`}
          onClick={() => {handleClick(3); showTab();}}
        >
          Delivery &amp; Returns
        </button>
        {
          showTab
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I am receiving this error which is telling me that it happens when I return a Component instead of  from render.

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Comment: try logging the changing values to see if the activieIndex really changes

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering `showTab` which is a function without calling it.

You can either convert it to a variable or call the function.

Also you don't need to call `showTab` on click when you are already handling the state with `activeIndex`.

Try this:

```js
export const Forcast = () => {
  // Create state to change tabs and return an index
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(1)

  const checkActive = (index, className) =>
    activeIndex === index ? className : ''

  // Create function to return a component depending on activeIndex value
  const activeTab = useMemo(() => {
    if (activeIndex === 1) {
      return <Today />
    } else if (activeIndex === 2) {
      return <Tomorrow />
    } else {
      return <SevenDays />
    }
  }, [activeIndex])

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="tabs">
        <button
          className={`tab ${checkActive(1, 'active')}`}
          onClick={() => setActiveIndex(1)}
        >
          Product Info
        </button>
        <button
          className={`tab ${checkActive(2, 'active')}`}
          onClick={() => setActiveIndex(2)}
        >
          Customer Reviews
        </button>
        <button
          className={`tab ${checkActive(3, 'active')}`}
          onClick={() => setActiveIndex(3)}
        >
          Delivery &amp; Returns
        </button>
        {activeTab}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution which is more simple and requires alot less code. Inside of the component I can just conditionally render by checking what **activeIndex** is equal to and return the component I would like.

```js
        {
          activeIndex === 1 ? <Today/> :
          activeIndex === 2 ? <Tomorrow /> :
          <SevenDays/>
        }
```